# NTFS permissions issue? Part of group which has access, but denied

Tags: windows, permissions, filesystems, ntfs, file-permissions

My account is part of Domain Admins, which is part of local machines Administrators group.

Such as:  MYDOMAIN\Domain Admins, is added to MY-LOCAL-PC\Administrators

I gave FULL CONTROL access to a folder, to MY-LOCAL-PC\Administrators, however I get denied access when I try to open it with my account.

Clearly, I am "recursively" allows access to this folder.  What may be the issue?

Comment: Are any groups set to DENY? Are any of your admins part of that group?

Comment: Can you provide the full rights? For example with output from `cacls`?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/446127/ntfs-domain-admins-dont-have-permissions-despite-being-part-of-the-local-admi

Answer (score 0):

I didn't consider UAC, as it skipped by mind (as I was file browsing, not trying to launch a process).  Of course, I'm running limited so "administrators" isn't part of my user token.  When I run something like Notepad "as admin", I can open that folder without an issue.

Simple issue, I just wasn't thinking clearly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[The link above](https://serverfault.com/q/446127/286236) pretty much covers this, but [this question](https://superuser.com/q/58933/443964) seems to make it much more clear that it's just not convenient to run Explorer as an Administrator as of Windows 7.

However, there was an [answer without much attention](https://superuser.com/a/844722/443964) that expands on what you said about using Notepad running as Administrator as a mini-explorer. I tested it out quickly, and I could cut&paste a file from a protected directory to somewhere else. I thought it was a pretty slick workaround.